# Actionscript / Flash co-ordinates

Tags: flash, actionscript, coordinates

This is a basic question in action script / flash. In most online examples / documentation I see that if a display object has width/height given as say (200, 200), then its pixel range is (0, 0) i.e. top-left and (200, 200) i.e. bottom-right. However since we're counting from 0 there are actually 201 pixels in each dimension right?

Answer (score 0):

width and height are in units.  Depending on your zoom/scale settings this could mean 1 unit per pixel. If the object has a height of 200 then it will start at 0 and end at 199.  It will be exactly 200 units high.

If you define the object to have a top-left corner of 0,0 and a bottom-right corner of 200,200 then the height and width of the object will be 201,201.  And the object will return those values if you ask it.

Perhaps an easier way to define the object is to set the top-left corner to be 0,0 or whatever you want and then set the width/height to 200,200.

Comment: This means to draw a horizontal line form the right edge to the left edge I would moveTo (199, 0) and lineTo(0, 0) right? But when I do this it leaves a gap on the right edge. But if I draw with moveTo(0,0) and lineTo(200,0) i.e. draw from left to right including (200,0) it draws correctly. Which means lineTo is leaving out the final point? And if that is the case why does it leave a gap when I draw from right to left?